# local inverse of polynomial

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, operator-theory

Is there a possibility to invert a polynomial locally? I've got the following problem, concerning control theory: Imagine a ideal amplifier with a feedback loop:

[image]

Let firstly A be not dependent on frequency. If A is linear we can write the following: $v_o = (v_1-v_2) \cdot A$ where $v_2=v_o \cdot F$
hence $v_o= (v_1-F \cdot v_o)A$
since A is linear we obtain:
$v_o=v_1 \cdot A- v_o \cdot A \cdot F$
hence
$v_o-AF v_o=v_1 \cdot A \rightarrow v_o=v_1\frac{ A}{1+A \cdot F}$

But now let A a polynomial, say of degree 3 and no offset: 
$A(x)= a_1 x+a_2 x^2+ a_3 x^3$. Then the equation above does not hold anymore. 
But we can assume we can invert the polynomial locally around zero, then the equation becomes (after some karate):
\begin{equation}
v_o= A(v_1-F \cdot v_o)\\
A^{-1}(v_o)= v_1 -F \cdot v_o \\ 
\text{assuming A is invertible locally} \\
F \cdot v_o + A^{-1}(v_o) = v_1\\
(F \cdot I + A^{-1})(v_o) = v_1 \\ \text{(is that correct?)}\\
v_o = (F \cdot I + A^{-1})^{-1}(v_1)\\
\end{equation}

Lastly we assume that the input signal $v_i$ is of the form $sin(\omega x)$ and we want to know how much the output sine is distorted (means the percentage of higher harmonics like $sin(2 \omega x)$ etc.) 
If we had found the operator $B = (F \cdot I + A^{-1})^{-1}$ we could run the input signal through it and do an FFT to find out about the distortion. 
We assume the coefficients $a_1 ... a_3 $to be reasonably arbitrary (so I can play around with them if possible), as is F. 
How do I find the operator $B$?
Is this somehow solvable by functional-analysis (since it is a non linear operator we cannot use the Neumann-series, or can we?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my specific problem: the keywords are Taylor series and Implicit Function Theorem. Imagine the x the input, y the output, f a non-linear function:
\begin{equation}
y= f(x-b \cdot y)\\
\end{equation}
(this is as above, just renamed). Then we can do the following: \begin{equation}
0= f(x-b \cdot y)-y\\
F(x,y(x))=0
\end{equation}
Means we have an implicit function. The implicit function theorem allows us under some assumptions that we can make to find the derivative of $y$ in a given point, we choose (x,y)=(0,0). So we have:
\begin{equation}
y^\prime = -\frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}
\end{equation} 
As $f(x)$ we have $a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$ so substituting $x$ by $x-by$ and differentiating we obtain (after setting x to zero in the counter and y to zero in denominator!):
\begin{equation}
 -\frac{a_1-2a_2by+3b^2y^2a_3}{-a_1b-2a_2bx-3x^2b-1}
\end{equation} 
Furthermore we set the remaining x's and y's to zero (which we could have done already) and obtain:
\begin{equation}
 \frac{a_1}{a_1b+1}
\end{equation} 
for $y'$ in the point (0,0). Further differentiating gives higher derivatives of y and we can use them as coefficients of a Taylor polynomial. This is somehow tiresome but will lead to exactly what I wanted. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So the dominant condition for invertibility is $a_1\ne 0$, and the "auxiliary" condition that the denominator is not zero. You can use the linear Taylor approximation as a predictor and correct the inverse value via Newtons method. This should be faster and more readable than the computation of the higher Taylor coefficients.

Comment: Thanks, could you please elaborate on that? As far as I understand you give some mathematical conditions needed to ensure the inverse exists. Since my calculation is for a very practical problem we can assume the existence of the inverse without further ado. The main goal I proofed with that is, that an amplifier with feedback is more linear than just attenuating the input signal into a more linear region of the amp. From the results one can beautifully see, that feedback makes the amp more linear by the factor of feedback. This is not a trivial result.

Comment: How do you use the Newton method in relation to this problem?

Comment: You treat $x$ as a parameter and solve $0=h(y)=F(x,y)$ for $y$. -- Also, if $b$ is very large then the equation is dominated by the leading powers in $b$, which is $a_3b^3y^3$ and with one order lower $(a_3(x-by)+a_2)b^2y^2$, which indeed forces an increasingly linear relationship $y=\dfrac{a_3x+a_2}{a_3b}$. However, explore for stability and error propagation due to the almost singular slope.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need linearity to write down Neumann series. Neumann series is just a fancy name for the geometric series: as long as the common ratio is less than 1 (in some norm), then it does converge (in that same norm).

Namely, if $\ ||AF||_*<1$ (for some *subadditive* norm $\|\cdot\|_*$), then

$$
\left\|(I-AF)^{-1} - \sum_{k=0}^n (AF)^k\right\|_* \to 0 \mbox{ as } n\to\infty.
$$

This is because $\|(AF)^k\|\leq\|AF\|^k\to 0$ as $k\to \infty$, and

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (AF)^k = (I - AF)^{-1} (I - (AF)^{n+1}).
$$

Comment: Oh good, thanks! So the Neumann series was my first intuition, but how do i do this now specifically? Let's assume an exponential function (hopefully for simplicity). The inverse is the logarithm. How could this be derived by using the Neumann series?

Comment: Wikipedia says, that the operator has to be linear...

Comment: I don't see it.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Comment: The only requirement is that it is bounded. But of course, that is implied by the assumption that its norm is less than 1.

Comment: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann-Reihe German Wikipedia says so. "stetig linear" = continuous linear. But if not so, how could this concretely be done for a function? I just did that long ago for I guess integral operators or something like that...

Comment: I think what you're doing is wrong in the non-linear case. In fact, $v_o= (v_1-F \cdot v_o)A$ is not the same as $v_o=v_1 \cdot A- v_o \cdot A \cdot F$, so you cannot get to the expression $v_o=v_1 \cdot A- v_o \cdot A \cdot F$.

Comment: Yeah that only holds for the linear case. The next equation however is true (I believe), see my edit. This is the problem. How do I find the inverse of the polynomial A?